# How to get google play purchase details for voided purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-developer-api, google-play-billing

I'm trying to implement processing of refunded google play purchases with google's [voided purchases API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/voided-purchases)

However, while the voided purchases API returns the purchase token, and the order ID, in order to retrieve the details of a purchase from the [purchases.products.get API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/get), you need to also provide the product ID (aka SKU).

Is there a way to retrieve the purchase without trying `purchases.products.get` for every known SKU?

Comment: No, unfortunately. We ended up changing our integration to not require the details. As far as I can tell, google expects you to track this on your end, even though there doesn't seem to be any practical reason for this limitation.